# How to get color-depth or pixel desnity right for a remote desktop to CentOS using VNCServer?

Tags: remote-desktop, centos, vnc, pixels, color-depth

I am doing a remote desktop to CentOS by starting VNCServer (Tiger VNC)and then connecting using RealVNC client. 
This is what I see

[image: CentOS Remote Desktop View with low pixel density]
There is something wrong with Pixel density, resolution or color-depth.

Can't figure out and how to fix it.

I have already tried installing fonts (msttcore) and starting server using various resolution and color depth.

> vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x768

Comment: What version of the RealVNC client (viewer) are you using?

Comment: VNC® Viewer 6.17.731 (r29523) x64 (Aug 3 2017 17:36:47)

Comment: When in a connection click the information button from the viewer's toolbar, what does it say for pixel format, VNC Server default, Requested Encoding and Last-used encoding?

Comment: @srk **Connection Information**
`Size: 1360x 768 
Pixel format: depth 6 (8 bpp) rgb222 
VNC Server default: depth 24 (32 bpp) little-endian rgb888 
Requested encoding: ZRLE 
Last-used encoding: ZRLE 
Line-speed estimate: 213 kbit/s (RTT —Oms) 
Protocol version: 3.8 
Security method: no encryption [VncAuth] 
Connection type: Direct TCP`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried changing the viewer's picture quality settings? While in a connection select the cog icon from the viewer's toolbar. Then set picture quality to High.

Comment: it solved the issue